# iOS & CoreAudio: Calling MusicPlayerSetTime() stops MusicPlayer

Tags: ios, core-audio, midi

I'm using CoreAudio on iOS 5 to play MIDI files. I have everything setup, it works, everything's peachy, except when I want to start over the sequence from the start **during the playback**.
To do that I naturally call:

```
    if (MusicPlayerSetTime(musicPlayer, (MusicTimeStamp)0.0) != noErr)
        [NSException raise:@"playMIDI" format:@"Can't reset the player"];
```

I don't get any error, but making this call stops the playback altogether, instead of (as is said in the documentation) continuing playing from the new position.
I have tried this also (and many other combinations of the same type):

```
Boolean isPlaying = NO;
if (MusicPlayerIsPlaying(musicPlayer, &isPlaying) != noErr)
    [NSException raise:@"playMIDI:" format:@"Can't get MusicPlayer play state"];

if (isPlaying) {
    if (MusicPlayerStop(musicPlayer) != noErr)
        [NSException raise:@"playMIDI:" format:@"Can't stop MusicPlayer"];
}

if (MusicPlayerSetSequence(musicPlayer, musicSequence) != noErr)
    [NSException raise:@"playMIDI:" format:@"Can't set sequence for MusicPlayer"];

if (MusicPlayerSetTime(musicPlayer, (MusicTimeStamp)0.0) != noErr)
    [NSException raise:@"playMIDI" format:@"Can't reset the player"];

if (MusicPlayerSetPlayRateScalar(musicPlayer, 1.0) != noErr)
    [NSException raise:@"playMIDI" format:@"Can't set speed"];

if (MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer) != noErr)
    [NSException raise:@"playMIDI" format:@"Can't start MusicPlayer"];
```

No joy, same effect.

If I change the MusicSequence however, the new MusicSequence plays fine. So I've gone to the extreme of creating two MusicSequence from the same MIDI file and switching from one to the other. No joy, iOS knows I want to play the same file twice and forbids it. I have to wait until the sequence is completely played before I can play it again. Bewildering.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's what I think is happening: Core Audio is pull-based, that is, when a unit needs data, it requests it from its source. Now when I reset the time on a MusicPlayer, it's done at a certain time, say t0. Shortly after, at time t1, the AU Node fed by this MusicPlayer asks for data. The MusicPlayer takes t1 and computes where it falls in its sequence of events. Since it is invariably greater than t0, any event that starts exactly at t0 (e.g. events that starts at MIDI tick 0) are considered played and are thus not played at all. In other words, the first note(s) of the midi files is/are not played.

Now, since my files are very short and in fact contain only a chord starting at tick 0, none of the notes are played and I get silence.

Why this isn't happening when I load a new sequence or start a sequence when it is not already playing is not clear to me...

Anyway, one possible fix is to: stop the player, set the sequence, set the time to 0 then delay the start of the player by e.g. 25ms. That is not ideal for responsiveness, but it works.

A slightly more convoluted way to fix this is the following:
- set up a callback on render on the audio unit the music player is feeding (AudioUnitAddRenderNotify())
- at the time of the reset of the sequence, don't reset the time on the player but set a boolean flag
- in the render callback, if the flag is set, reset the time on the player and unset the flag
There is no delay introduced and it also works, which tends to validate my interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't noticed any problem with starting/stopping/restarting a sequence at t0. Are you confident that notes in the sequence are at the times you think they are? Or something else going on?

A quick test with the code below (error checking removed) stops + restarts fine. Or perhaps I misunderstood the issue you described. Fwiw - without the stop/start player calls, it also works but transient notes will still sound so it is less of a clean jump.

```
- (void)jump
{
    if (player) {
        MusicPlayerStop(player)
        MusicPlayerSetTime(player, 0.0f);
        MusicPlayerStart(player);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I took a look at the .mid file and tested it. This is how the MusicPlayer sees your file (using the function `CAShow(nameOfYourSequence)`)

```
Sequence @0x68ad7c0
NumTracks = 1, Type = beats
* * TempoTrack * *
SequenceTrack @0x68ab250
    Num Events: 3, Track Length: 0.00 beats
    0.000: Time Sig:4/4, 24 clks/qtr, 8 32nds/clk
    0.000: SMPTE Offset [33:0:0:0.0]
    0.000: Tempo:120.000

* * Track 1 * *
SequenceTrack @0x6a815e0
    Num Events: 9, Track Length: 4.11 beats
    0.000: MetaEvent:03
         0:  30 31 30 31 30 31 31 31                           01010111        
    0.000: MetaEvent:04
         0:  30 31 20 43                                       01 C            
    0.000: MetaEvent:59
         0:  00 00                                             ..              
    0.000: MetaEvent:06
         0:  31 20 4D 41 4A 45 55 52 53                        1 MAJEURS       
    0.000: MetaEvent:06
         0:  31 31                                             11              
    0.000: Note:Ch:0 36 121 (4.113)
    0.000: Note:Ch:0 60 116 (3.931)
    0.000: Note:Ch:0 64 110 (3.931)
    0.000: Note:Ch:0 67 105 (3.931)
```

I was able to repro the issue with that file - hadn't seen it before but then the files I work are longer. Don't know what you are trying to do but a workaround might be starting your event a bit later than 0.000.

On the other hand, have you considered managing your noteOn + noteOff events directly using:

```
MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I checked, the notes start at 0 (I used http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/ to dump the content of the file, and I also checked with Aria Maestosa). I must say I am at a loss to explain the behavior, except with the interpretation I give below.

Comment: I've wrestled with MusicPlayer quite a bit so I understand feeling at a loss! Anything unusual about the tempo, play rate? Can't think of anything else.

Comment: The midi file is so simple it's hard to have anything wrong in it, but here, judge by yourself: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3916368/01010111.mid.  Let me know if you manage to restart it, say, 1 second after first playing it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot skinnyTOD, I'm glad (well, sorta...) that you're able to reproduce the problem, at least I know it's real. I'm using this in a music application where chords are played following user actions. Latency is an issue and I am loath to introduce an artificial delay in the file. I could do the sequencing myself as you suggest, if it were not for the other, more complex, midi files I need to play. And also, it feels wrong to have to redo Apple's work to work around such a silly bug. But then again, I may end up doing that because the fixes I suggest don't work 100%.